# How to create references per chapter and complete references section in quarto book pdf?

Tags: r, lua, quarto

I'm working on a Quarto book that I need in pdf output. I need to create references per chapter and also the complete document references.

For the references per chapter, I found the following extension:

https://github.com/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies#quarto

That one solved my problem with references per chapter pretty well! Now the issue that I have is that I need to obtain the complete document references placed before my last section which is the appendices.

Here is how I'm using the lua filter:

```
    filters:
      - section-bibliographies.lua #This is the lua filter stated above
    bibliography: rap_v002.bib
    citeproc: true
```

I know that if citeproc is false is not going to generate the complete references section. If set up as true, it is going to generate the complete document references but at the very end of the document (after the appendices). I need to place those references before the appendices. This is how I have the _quarto.yml:

```
  chapters:
    - abstract.qmd
    - index.qmd
    - dedication.qmd
    - acknowledgements.qmd
    - list_abbreviations.qmd
    - chapter_1_intro.qmd
    - chapter_2_lm.qmd
    - chapter_3_ml.qmd
    - chapter_4_conclusions.qmd
    - bibliography.qmd
  appendices:
    - appendices.qmd
```

Inside the bibliography.qmd file I have the following:

```
# References {.unnumbered}

::: {#refs}
:::
```

I understand that the lua filter changes the pandoc behavior about those `#refs` to create the references per chapter. I have tried to change it without success.

Do you have any recommendations on how to achieve placing the complete document references before the appendices without messing up the references per chapter already created with the lua filter?

Comment: Can you share a test GitHub repository with all the necessary files so that per-chapter references are created?. Because I can not even get per-chapter bibliography, let alone at the end bibliography. I am having [the same issue now](https://github.com/pandoc-ext/section-bibliographies/issues/13)

Comment: Hi @shafee!, here I have an example with the bare minimum to create a pdf with references per chapter. In the readme, I wrote a couple of links with extra info. https://github.com/ronnyhdez/quarto_references_per_chapter